# How to apply patch on init.d?

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, ubuntu, patch

I tried to install mongodb on my machine using [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) guide.

However I ran into [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8774) problem. This link also contains a patch. The patch file is `init.d.patch`

I tried:

```
root@DevUbuntu12:/etc# sudo patch -p1 < /home/hadoop/Downloads/init.d.patch
```

But got an error:

```
patch: **** File init.d is not a regular file -- can't patch
```

How can I apply this patch?

Comment: The patch operates on a file called `init.d` but in `/etc` there is a directory called `init.d`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of patching, I would suggest to install "numactl". The patch is made against the source tree, and not the installed version so the files are all wrong. You can still use the patch, but running:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo patch -p2 < /tmp/init.d.patch
```

It then warns about not knowing the name and lets you enter it yourself. Enter:

```
mongodb
```

My session looked like:

```sh
derick@whisky:~ $ cd /etc

derick@whisky:/etc $ cd init.d/

derick@whisky:/etc/init.d $ sudo patch -p2 < /tmp/init.d2.patch 
can't find file to patch at input line 7
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git debian/init.d debian/init.d
|old mode 100644
|new mode 100755
|index 7e5169d..4577291
|--- debian/init.d
|+++ debian/init.d
--------------------------
File to patch: mongodb
patching file mongodb

derick@whisky:/etc/init.d $
```